# Как сделать из Json Model Pojo?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

> [ссылка на json](https://api.knowledgecity.com/v2/portals/86404e63-45d3-47d2-9c3c-b33efa6df4d6/course/0BUS1125/?lang=en)

Вся проблема в chapters. по сути это гавнокод такие вещи надо в массиве добавлять. Но что есть то есть. Как мне этот Json сделать в Pojo (Gson). Таким образом чтобы `chapters` был в массиве, а не как 5 отдельных объектов. Так как они всегда динамические.

А эту модель я хочу использовать для всех запросов такого типа.

Я знаю что надо как то `chapters` добавить в `List<>` или `HashMap`

Comment: Ну так и в чем вопрос то? Это же чистой воды `HashMap`

Comment: @rjhdby, Вот картина https://i.ytimg.com/vi/k_oWVmveUuY/maxresdefault.jpg. Это называется Pojo Model.

Как мне сделать из Json вот такую модель.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно написать свой `JsonDeserializer<Chapter[]>`, который будет считывать json в `Map<String, Chapter>` (где `Chapter` это класс, представляющий главу), а затем этот `Map` преобразовывать в `Chapter[]` (используя методы [`Map::values`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) и [`Collection::toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray-T:A-)).

Например, если json выглядит примерно так:

```
{
  "chapters": {
    "5767ab95-8ab0-490b-8c08-cd4963567f75": {
      "title": "Welcome"
    },
    "2eec0125-1613-4ed7-81b5-c10b55ba3e3d": {
      "title": "Understanding the Rules of the Game"
    },
    "21e66272-76bc-4586-a02f-c64bdaad9d4f": {
      "title": "Understanding Personality "
    }
  }
}
```

то можно написать такой код:

```
static class Chapter {
    String title;
    // остальные поля
}

static class Data {
    Chapter[] chapters;
    // остальные поля
}

static class ChapterArrayAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Chapter[]> {
    @Override
    public Chapter[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        // получаем тип для Map<String, Chapter>
        Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Chapter>>() {}.getType();
        // десериализуем Map<String, Chapter>
        Map<String, Chapter> map = context.deserialize(json, mapType);
        // преобразуем в массив
        return map.values().toArray(new Chapter[0]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Chapter[].class, new ChapterArrayAdapter());
    Gson gson = builder.create();

    Data data = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("data.json"), Data.class);
}
```